# I jumped branches and now my code is lost, how to restore it

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

First of all would say I am new to using repos. Being said that I did some changes and did a commit today but for some reason it was not going through some file was too big etc. So I jumped to main branch and everything is lost.

I don't see my code any where even though I moved back to

> 9d85487f835d73c02a818772ed58d73c9d53352c

But everything seems gone ...Please help

[image]

** UPDATE*************

I do see old files but in one case the whole file is missing and in another see below:

[image]

****** FURTHER UPDATE****************

```
 PS E:\Websites\sampleSite\src\presentation> git status
Refresh index: 100% (24853/24853), done.
On branch 9d85487f835d73c02a818772ed58d73c9d53352c
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   Nop.Web/Controllers/HomeController.cs
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/DiscountRules.CustomerRoles/Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.CustomerRoles.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/DiscountRules.CustomerRoles/Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.CustomerRoles.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/ExchangeRate.EcbExchange/Nop.Plugin.ExchangeRate.EcbExchange.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/ExchangeRate.EcbExchange/Nop.Plugin.ExchangeRate.EcbExchange.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/ExternalAuth.Facebook/Nop.Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/ExternalAuth.Facebook/Nop.Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Misc.Sendinblue/Nop.Plugin.Misc.Sendinblue.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Misc.Sendinblue/Nop.Plugin.Misc.Sendinblue.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Misc.WebApi.Frontend/Nop.Plugin.Misc.WebApi.Frontend.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Misc.WebApi.Frontend/Nop.Plugin.Misc.WebApi.Frontend.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/MultiFactorAuth.GoogleAuthenticator/Nop.Plugin.MultiFactorAuth.GoogleAuthenticator.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/MultiFactorAuth.GoogleAuthenticator/Nop.Plugin.MultiFactorAuth.GoogleAuthenticator.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Payments.CheckMoneyOrder/Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Payments.CheckMoneyOrder/Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Payments.Manual/Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Payments.Manual/Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Payments.PayPalCommerce/Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalCommerce.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Payments.PayPalCommerce/Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalCommerce.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Payments.PayPalStandard/Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Payments.PayPalStandard/Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Pickup.PickupInStore/Nop.Plugin.Pickup.PickupInStore.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Pickup.PickupInStore/Nop.Plugin.Pickup.PickupInStore.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Shipping.EasyPost/Nop.Plugin.Shipping.EasyPost.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Shipping.EasyPost/Nop.Plugin.Shipping.EasyPost.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal/Nop.Plugin.Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal/Nop.Plugin.Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Shipping.UPS/Nop.Plugin.Shipping.UPS.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Shipping.UPS/Nop.Plugin.Shipping.UPS.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Tax.Avalara/Nop.Plugin.Tax.Avalara.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Tax.Avalara/Nop.Plugin.Tax.Avalara.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Tax.FixedOrByCountryStateZip/Nop.Plugin.Tax.FixedOrByCountryStateZip.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Tax.FixedOrByCountryStateZip/Nop.Plugin.Tax.FixedOrByCountryStateZip.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.AccessiBe/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.AccessiBe.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.AccessiBe/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.AccessiBe.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.FacebookPixel/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.FacebookPixel.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.FacebookPixel/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.FacebookPixel.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.GoogleAnalytics/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.GoogleAnalytics.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.GoogleAnalytics/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.GoogleAnalytics.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.NivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.NivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.What3words/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.What3words.dll
        modified:   Nop.Web/Plugins/Widgets.What3words/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.What3words.pdb
        modified:   Nop.Web/obj/Debug/net6.0/Nop.Web.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache
        modified:   Nop.Web/obj/Debug/net6.0/project.razor.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: can you run `git branch`, and check if you have a *branch* named `9d8548...` ?

Comment: Nope. Only show main

Comment: hmm ... can you add to your question the output of `cat .git/HEAD` ? (note: please copy the text in your terminal, rather than a screenshot)

Comment: Actually I do see it now , but i did not see it before I think it started showing when i did git checkout  9d8548... As I moved back to it from main freaking out I do see some pages have the correct code latest but others dont .. The ones which were already conflicting and not merged etc.

Comment: ok, probably a `git switch -c 9d8548...` instead of a plain `git switch ...` ? (or `git checkout -b` instead of `git checkout`)

Comment: Both when i do say : fatal: A branch named '9d85487f835d73c02a818772ed58d73c9d53352c' already exists.

Comment: Did you create an (auto-)stash? `git stash list` (or `git stash list -p`) to show

Comment: Nope. I only would have stashed some commit some time ago but the issue was each time i would try to commit it would say somethign again head and told me to use :
git push origin head:main something like that... So i got tired of tired move to main to see whats going on and lost it all

Comment: Main concern now is if some files are still new why are not the others which i pasted above

Comment: What's the output of `git status` (and maybe `git diff`)? What about commit `da02435`? Please [edit] your question to update the information _as text_.

Comment: @knittl have done for git status the other two are too big to paste I mean toooo big.

Comment: @confusedMind and what does the diff show? Does it contain the content of your file and remove all lines? Try running `git stash` (without any arguments). And will temporarily put away all your changes. Maybe that "brings back" your changes (which have been committed, but removed from your worktree?)

Comment: @knittl yeah I do see the code which I can recognize. But just to be on same page I did commit earlier but it was never pushed cause I had some .rar > 100MB . So should I still do the above?

Comment: @confusedMind yes, `stash` is – like most Git commands – a fully local operation. To restore the stashed changes, run `git stash apply`.

Comment: @confusedMind: I realize I added to the confusion :D I didn't mean to *run* `git checkout -b ...`, I meant that you probably created such a branch because you used the `-b` option rather than running a plain `git checkout ...` (without the `-b` option). I strongly advise *not* to create branch or tags with names that lead to ambiguity with commit hashes. See my answer on how to fix this.

Comment: @LeGEC what about the files/code will I get it back as its not on the Main so not sure why I remove 9d8... and move to main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a branch which has a name similar to the sha1 of one of your commits.

To confirm that : run `git branch`, and see if you see a branch named `9d85487f835d73c02a818772ed58d73c9d53352c` in the output.

You could have reached that state if you ran `git checkout -b 9d854...` instead of `git checkout 9d854...` :

- the first command (with `-b`) will create a branch named `9d854...` pointing at the current commit (you were on the `main` branch at that time)
- the second command (*without* `-b`) will switch to that commit, in a detached HEAD state

---

To fix that :

- switch away from that branch: `git switch main`
- delete that branch: `git branch -d 9d85487f835d73c02a818772ed58d73c9d53352c` (if you see a message stating "can't delete branch that isn't merged ...", use `-D` -- uppercase D -- to force deletion)

Things should now be back to normal.

- you can run `git log --graph --oneline 9d85487` to confirm that the history of commits is there,
- if you want to integrate that commit to the `main` branch, merge that commit into `main`:

```
git switch main
git merge 9d85487
```

- if you want to create your own `feature` branch, create a new branch named `feature` starting from that commit:

```
git switch -c feature 9d85487
```

Comment: added more info to the question please check.

Comment: PS E:\Websites\xxx\src\presentation> git log --graph --onelin 9d85487
fatal: unrecognized argument: --onelin

Comment: OK I do see the a list of commit and i can see vehicle working in there aswell. So will follow up lets c :)

Comment: Thanx a lot I think I got them back :D .. But how do I resolve this now on all and what to put so I don't mess it again : Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.